# Sed and replacing a string which has the character '\'

Tags: bash, sed

I have a Bash variable with a string in JSON format.

`FOO="[{\"name\": \"${NAME}\", \"surname\": \"${SURNAME}\"}]"`

The content of this variable is then replaced in a file with sed.

`sed -ie "s/<FOO>/$FOO/g" bar.txt`

For example, if `NAME=John` and `SURNAME=Doe`, I need the string in `bar.txt` to be exactly `"[{\"name\": \"John\", \"surname\": \"Doe\"}]"`, but sed is removing the backslashes.

So, how can I manage to do this replace? Tried to use triplets of backslashes (e.g. `\\\"name`...) but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do this; try:

```
FOO='[{\\"name\": \\"'${NAME}'\\", \\"surname\\": \\"'${SURNAME}'\\"}]"'
```

in the assignment, i.e. use single quotes and don't embed the NAME and SURNAMEs in a single string, instead allow the shell to concatenate everything.  That will prevent bash from interpolating the backslashes away.  If you

```
echo $FOO
```

you'll be able to see how this affects the value assigned to FOO.

(It's not sed that's removing the backslashes, it's bash.)

Comment: forgot to mention that John and Doe are actually other bash variables, so I can't use single quotes because it will parse them as strings (e.g. `"name": "$NAME"` instead of `"name": "John"`)

Comment: Sorry, had to step away.  Have revised in light of your change to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FOO='[{\"name\": \"John\", \"surname\": \"Doe\"}]'
sed -ie "s/<FOO>/${FOO//\"/\\\"}/g" bar.txt
```

Comment: check my updated question, sorry it was a comment to a previous answer that was deleted.. Actually John and Doe are other variables, so I can't use `'` as string delimiter, need to use `"`.